# How to read specific words in lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to this and currently I'm trying to create a sign up and log in system for my assignment and I did this.

```
def signUp(): #USER SIGN UP
    name=(str(input("Name: ")))
    intake=(str(input("Intake: ")))
    hp=(str(input("Phone Number: ")))
    email=(str(input("E-mail: ")))
    tp=(str(input("Student ID: ")))
    pw=(str(input("Password: ")))
    OccupantsData=[name,intake,hp,email,tp,pw]
    file=open("Database.txt","a")
    file.write(str(OccupantsData)+"\n")
    file.close()
```

When I run this code, it'll save all the inputs into 'Database.txt' like this

```
    ['James', 'Jul17', '1234', 'etc@etc.com', 'TP1234', 'password']

    ['Jon', 'Sep17', '5567', 'etc1@etc.com', 'TP2345', 'passwords']

    ['Han', 'Oct17', '7554', 'etc2@etc.com', 'TP5546', 'passwords1']

    ['Klye', 'Oct17', '2234', 'etc3@etc.com', 'TP0094', 'passwords2']
```

Now, i'm not sure how code the login... It should take in the TPnumber and make sure it matches the password on the line... When I code it this way, it only works for the TPnumber and password on the first line and it will not work for others...

```
def logIn(): #USER SIGN IN
    TP=str(input("Please input TP Number:"))
    password=input("Please input password:")
    f=open("Database.txt","r")
    user=f.read()
    if (TP) in user:
        if password in user:
            print("Welcome")
        else:
            print ("Username or Password doesn't match")
            logIn()
    else:
        print("Error")
        logIn()
```

What can I do to make it read the input username and password and not just the first line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend outputting a json file instead of a text file and look up data as a dictionary.  However, since you write lines that look like lists, you can evaluate the string as if it were an actual list with `ast.literal_eval()`.

**Given**

A file `Database.txt`

```
['James', 'Jul17', '1234', 'etc@etc.com', 'TP1234', 'password']
['Jon', 'Sep17', '5567', 'etc1@etc.com', 'TP2345', 'passwords']
['Han', 'Oct17', '7554', 'etc2@etc.com', 'TP5546', 'passwords1']
['Klye', 'Oct17', '2234', 'etc3@etc.com', 'TP0094', 'passwords2']
```

created from this refactored function:

```
def signup():
    """User sign up."""
    name  = str(input("Name: "))
    intake = (str(input("Intake: ")))
    hp = str(input("Phone Number: "))
    email = str(input("E-mail: "))
    tp = str(input("Student ID: "))
    pw = str(input("Password: "))
    occupants_data = [name, intake, hp, email, tp, pw]

    # Safely open/close files
    with open("Database.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(str(occupants_data) + "\n")
```

**Code**

```
from ast import literal_eval


def login(): 
    """User sign in."""
    tp = str(input("Please input TP Number: "))
    password = str(input("Please input password: "))

    with open("Database.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if not line or line =="\n":
                continue

            user_data = literal_eval(line)         # convert string-list to a list
            if tp == user_data[-2]:
                if password == user_data[-1]:
                    print("Welcome")
                    return
                else:
                    print ("Username or Password doesn't match")
                    return
        print("Error")
```

**Demo**

[image]

---

**Details**

The `signup()` function was refactored by:

- lowercase function name according to PEP8
- extra parentheses removed
- the `with` statement was used to safely open and close files

This can be used to generate the `Database.txt` file.

The `login()` function was refactored by:

- lowercase function and variable names
- converting the password input to a string
- using a `with` statement to handle the file
- iterating each line of the file, ignoring blank lines and newlines
- list-like lines are converted to lists
- rather than search lists, data is more quickly pulled from fixed indices
- the loop short-circuits if an input is successful, otherwise an error is printed

The next concept you might consider is [exception handling](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_exceptions.htm) raising errors instead of printing them and handling user `KeyboardInterupt` to quit a prompt.

Answer (score 0):

In order to match the input with one or more of the *txt* file content, you need to loop over it. Moreover, to check if password is in the list you have to cast it into *string* . So your login code would become:

```
def logIn():  # USER SIGN IN
TP = str(input("Please input TP Number:"))
password = str(input("Please input password:"))
f = open("Database.txt", "r")
for line in f.readlines():
    if (TP) in line:
        if password in line:
            print("Welcome")
        else:
            print ("Username or Password doesn't match")
            logIn()
    else:
        print("Error")
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

`input()` returns a string, so no need for explicit conversion with `str()`.  Better use `with statement` when dealing with file objects as it closes them automatically.

Defining `signUp()`:

```
def signUp(): #USER SIGN UP    
    name = input("Name: ")
    intake = input("Intake: ")
    hp = input("Phone Number: ")
    email = input("E-mail: ")
    tp = input("Student ID: ")
    pw = input("Password: ")

    OccupantsData = [name, intake, hp, email, tp, pw]

    with open("Database.txt", "a") as db:
        db.write(' '.join(OccupantsData)) # Writing it as a string
```

Calling `signUp()`:

```
signUp()

Name: x
Intake: something
Phone Number: 123-456-7890
E-mail: x@email.com
Student ID: x123
Password: password
>>>
```

Defining `logIn()`:

```
def logIn(): #USER SIGN IN
    TP = input("Please input TP Number: ")
    password = input("Please input password: ")

    with open("Database.txt") as db:
        for line in db:
            line = line.split(' ') # Making it a list

            if TP in line:
                if password in line:
                    print("Welcome")
                else:
                    print ("Username or Password doesn't match")
                    logIn()
            else:
                print("Error")
                logIn()
```

Calling `logIn()`:

```
logIn()

Please input TP Number: x123
Please input password: pass
Username or Password doesn't match
Please input TP Number: x123
Please input password: password
Welcome
>>>
```

[Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) says:

> It is good practice to use the [with](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) keyword when dealing with file objects. The advantage is that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised at some point.

Comment: 1) You should add db.write ('\n') to the code; otherwise, you'll end up with "password<name>" in your list.  Example:  ['Ted', 'something', '123-456-7890', 'x@email.com', 'x134', 'passwordTom', 'somethingelse', '321-111-5555', 'y@email.com', 'y123'
2) If you do add a new line, make sure to include in line = line.strip ().split (' ')
3)  If you add the following 2 suggestions, the logIn () code will need to be rewrite because if line [0] doesn't have the correct credential but line [1] does, you'll keep getting repeated "error" even though the loop hasn't fully traverse through the list.

Comment: ..or leave the fun to the OPS.